# Showing a signed Borel measure is $0$ (Practice Qual question)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define the signed Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ by $d\mu = fdm$. Assume $\int_{[0,1]} x^n d\mu = 0,$ $n=0,1,2, \cdots$
>
> Prove that $\mu = 0$

My first thought is to assume $\mu \neq 0$ and then show this contradicts$\int_{[0,1]} x^n d\mu = 0$ for some $n$. I don't think I'm allowed to "substitute" and look at $\int_{[0,1]} x^nf(x) dm$, so I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: suggestion - use (Stone-)Weierstrass: polys are dense in the space of cts functions on the closed (unit) interval (sup  norm).

Comment: Rereading your question.... Why do you think that you aren't allowed to substitute? You can - it's the definition of $d\mu$.

Comment: Because a lot of things in real analysis I thought I should be allowed to do I'm not actually allowed to, so I figured I should ask. I'm not sure how to use Stone-Weierstrass here. So I can approximate f by a polynomial (call it g), so then g*x^n is another polynomial.

Comment: Show that $\int f^2 \,dx = 0$. You know that $\int  gf\, dx = 0$, where $g$ is a poly, so $ \int f^2 \,dx = \int (f - g) f \,dx .$

Comment: What is the OP's definition of $d\mu = fdm?$

Comment: @peterag Why do I know that $\int gf dx = 0$? And why does showing $\int f^2 dx = 0$ help for this problem? I'm sure it will but I'm not seeing why

Comment: @zhw. It means $\mu(E) = \int_E f dm$ for each Borel set $E$

Comment: Because $f^2$ is a continuous positive function, so if its integral is zero, it is zero. $g$ is a (finite) linear combination of $x^n$, and so if $\int x^n f (x)\, dx = 0$, so is $\int g f\, dx = 0$.

Comment: Regarding @zhw's question, and your answer - I said  'by definition' that you could substitute: the 'by definition' is over-stating it a bit I was thinking of the (or 'a') Riesz representation theorem - giving a bounded linear functional on the space of cts functions gives a measure. In any event, you certainly can substitute.

Comment: @Brenton OK, that's what I thought. So you need to show $\int g d\mu = \int g f dm.$ Try it for a simple function, and proceed ...

Comment: @zhw  - i totally disagree! the OP does not need to show the equality $\int g\, d\mu = \int g f \, dm$, as it has to be a given, certainly no less than the Stone Weierstrass, for the question. Or - let me temper that - I can't believe that the examiner would expect a person answering the qual exam question, as stated, also to prove $\int g\, d\mu = \int g f \, dm$ along the way.

Comment: @peterag It does not have to be a given; it could be part of the problem.